# Add two parameters in URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code that will get the inputs of two texboxes (stud_firstname and stud_lastname):

```
function chkstudname(val)
  {
    var firstName = $("input[name=stud_firstname]").val();
    var lastName = $("input[name=stud_lastname]").val();
      $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"check_stud_name.php",
        data:'fname='+firstName+'lname='+lastName,
        success: function(data){
          $("#msg_stud_name").html(data);
        }
      });
  }
```

I want to somehow generate a url like this:

```
check_stud_name.php?fname=Bill&lname=GATES
```

I can do it in `php` but `javascipt` isn't exactly my thing so I don't know how to do it. The above code works but it assigned the `fname` only, the `lname` is unknown. 

So if I entered BILL to the firstname box, and GATES to the lastname box, given this php code:

```
$fname = $_GET[fname];
$lname= $_GET['lname'];

echo $fname."<separator to check if it works>".$lname;
```

the output is:

```
BILLlname=GATES<separator to check if it works>
```

and gives out an error saying that `$_GET['lname']` is not found. So it's safe to assume that the value of `fname` is `BILLlname=GATES` and the "lname=..." code doesn't work since it merged with the "fname=..."

How can I put two variables/parameters in the url and make the `lname=...` work? I tried putting `&` in between them but it doesn't work at all..

Comment: Unless you expect the `&` to magically appear all by itself, I suggest _you_ insert one between the two name=value-pairs. // You completely neglected URL-encoding here. Look into jQuery’s `.serialize`, that handles stuff like that for you.

Comment: `check_stud_name.php?fname=Bill&lname=GATES` is GET format but you're using POST to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty basic just add `&`

change

```
data:'fname='+firstName+'lname='+lastName,
```

to

```
data:'fname='+firstName+'&lname='+lastName,
```

Answer (score 0):

## Separators

URL encoded form data is a set of key=value pairs separated with `&` characters. You need to actually include the `&` characters.

## Escaping

Certain characters (such as `=` and `&`) have special meaning in URLs.

You should escape user input before adding them to a URL.

## POST requests

jQuery puts the value of the `data` parameter for a POST request *in the request body*.

If you want to make a POST request with a query string, then you need to put it in the query string of the URL explicitly.

## Code

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url:"check_stud_name.php?fname=" + encodeURIComponent(firstName) + "?lname=" + encodeURIComponent(lastName),
    // etc
```

## Alternatively: GET

It looks like you are trying to GET data, so you should be making a GET request instead of a POST request.

You can pass jQuery's `data` field an object and have jQuery escape it and form the query string for you:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "GET",
    url: "check_stud_name.php",
    data: {
        fname: firstName,
        lname: lastName
    }
    // etc
```